# Can we edit the webbrowser library in python to open the webpage in the same tab?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-webbrowser

Can we edit the `webbrowser` library in Python to open the webpage in the same tab by using the statement:

```
webbrowser.open(url,new=0,autoraise=False)
```

I am using Windows operating system and Chrome browser.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: It's open source, so do you can make whatever modifications you wish.

Comment: I tried manipulating the library but not sure if  I'm doing it right. It would be helpful if someone who understand the complete library helps out in doing the above modifications.